# SQL command not properly ended when using a join

Tags: sql

I'm trying to use a JOIN in my query and can't figure out why I'm getting a

> SQL command not properly ended

error. Here's the query I'm trying to run:

```
select 
    v.contid, v.group_id, a.user_id 
from 
    application_users a, web_users v
where 
    a.is_active = 1
    and v.group_id in (22, 26, 595, 635)
    and a.user_id = v.user_id
join 
    contest_results cr on cr.user_id = a.user_id
where 
    cr.period = 201502
```

Comment: you just tried to mix explicit and implicit joins syntax

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: All the **JOIN** first, then all the **WHERE** clause elements .. don't mix those two

Answer (score 4):

Thats not the right syntax to `JOIN` multiple tables.

Also don't use comma separated join always use proper `INNER JOIN` syntax which is more readable. Try this

```
SELECT v.contid, 
       v.group_id, 
       a.user_id 
FROM   application_users a 
       INNER JOIN web_users v 
               ON a.user_id = v.user_id 
       INNER JOIN contest_results cr 
               ON cr.user_id = a.user_id 
WHERE  cr.period = 201502 
       AND a.is_active = 1 
       AND v.group_id IN ( 22, 26, 595, 635 )
```